# Using variable as a path delete old files

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

START_TIME=$(date +%s)
timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
path=$pathfile
filename=logFile_$timestamp.txt

find $pathfile -name "*.txt"  -type f -mtime +10 -print >> /root/$filename

echo "Backup:: Script Start -- $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> /root/$filename

END_TIME=$(date +%s)

ELAPSED_TIME=$(expr $END_TIME - $START_TIME)

echo "Backup :: Script End -- $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> /root/$filename
echo "Elapsed Time ::  $(date -d 00:00:$ELAPSED_TIME +%Hh:%Mm:%Ss) ">>  /root/$filename
```

I want to delete files from a specific paths and the paths will be defined in a separate file. So the script is written as mention below to read path from a file but the issue is script is not pick up the path mention in the file. can some one help.
File name: pathfile
/root/abc/dir1
/root/xyz/dir2
/etc/var/dir3

Comment: Note: your `START_TIME` and `timestamp` can be different. Best to use: `timestamp=$(date -d @"$START_TIME" +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)` if you intend they are the same. Also, you will not have write permission in `/root` unless you are running the script as `root`.

Comment: Is there one path in the file or multiple paths? If so, is it one path per line or is it separated in some other ways? Also, can the paths contain spaces?

Comment: You should also test `[ -d "$pathfile" ]` to validate that you actually have a valid path.

Comment: Yes there is multiple path in files .. I tried using one path in a line also multiple path in a line separated with space. but still its not helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am following this correctly, you have a file which at some point you assign to the variable "pathfile" and it contains the following entries:

```
/root/abc/dir1
/root/xyz/dir2
/etc/var/dir3
```

Assuming the above is true, find command does not read from files, so you would need to use a while loop to read from the file and then call the find command with the resulting path:

```
while read -r path
do
  find "$path" -name "*.txt"  -type f -mtime +10 -print >> /root/$filename
  echo "Backup:: Script Start -- $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> /root/$filename

  END_TIME=$(date +%s)

  ELAPSED_TIME=$(expr $END_TIME - $START_TIME)
  # Alternative -- (( ELAPSED_TIME = END_TIME - START_TIME ))
  echo "Backup :: Script End -- $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> /root/$filename
  echo "Elapsed Time ::  $(date -d 00:00:$ELAPSED_TIME +%Hh:%Mm:%Ss) ">>  /root/$filename
done<"$pathfile"
```

If I have misunderstood you may need to explain further?

Comment: Hi grail, yes assumption is true.. file contains the above mention path.

Comment: Also I tried to run code you mentioned but its giving me this error:

Comment: line 20: : No such file or directory

Comment: I assume you have set pathfile, filename and START_TIME variables somewhere before running my code? If you have, you would need to show the errored line as I obviously do not have 20 lines of code?

Comment: I have add in script below lines to define variable and rest remain same as you mentioned.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

START_TIME=$(date +%s)
timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
#path="/root/script"
path=$pathfile
filename=logFile_$timestamp.txt

Comment: So the variable, "pathfile" is never set, hence the script will not work as it is trying to read from nothing.  Set pathfile variable to the name of the file that contains the paths we want to work on.